# How to manually create a decision tree in Weka

Tags: weka, decision-tree

I would like to create my own decision tree model in Weka. In other words, I would like to manually specify all the splits and all the split values in the decision tree, without training any of the decision tree algorithms (e.g. REPTree, J48, etc.) on data. Is this possible in the Weka GUI or through Weka's Java API? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Not that I'm aware of. You will need to create your own classifier, with the relevant options that define the splits that you want to use (or point to a file that contains that information for you to parse).